# Accessing music directories with eyed3 tool

Tags: python-3.x, eyed3

I am creating a music application currently and i have saved my music in a separate folder called music. Now, I want to loop and get every music and get all music's information with eyed3. The main problem here is that it seems that eyed3 can only load music from parent directory. Is there a solution to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Code:

```
def load_songs(self):
        self.music_path = "D:\Music App\music"
        self.music_files = os.listdir(self.music_path)

        for i in range(len(self.music_files)):
            self.music = eyed3.load(self.music_files[i])
```

Error:
line 436, in load
raise IOError(f"file not found: {path}")
OSError: file not found: Bieber_-_Yummy.mp3

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here, only a bit complex. You've to provide the full path of the song.

```
def load_songs(self):
        self.music_path = "D:\Music App\music"
        self.music_files = os.listdir(self.music_path)

        for i in range(len(self.music_files)):
            self.music = TinyTag.get(f"D:\Music App\music\{self.music_files[i]}")
```